# charAt is giving me StringIndexOutOfBoundsException Exception

Tags: java

I'm trying to use CharAt to pharse a csv file.  I am trying to get the index of the commas , so I can find the position of each number.

Each string has 2 commas in it, when I search for the char , I get the exception.

To make sure there is really a comma in the string, I hard coded it.  I'm still getting the exception.

```
                    while ((t= in.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // read iun line   

                        // extract data

                        t="45446,45456456,464646";
                        // EXCEPTION GOES OFF HERE
                        p=t.charAt(',');



                        sTimeStamp=t.substring(0, p-1);
                        t=t.substring(p+1);

                        p=t.charAt(',');
                        sPoint=t.substring(0, p-1);
                        t=t.substring(p+1);                         

                        p=t.charAt(',');
                        sVol=t.substring(0, p-1);


                        // store data   
                    }

                    LoadGraph(reply);
                    System.out.println("finish Read indata");                
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return "nn";
              }
```

Comment: Okay, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: What do you think `charAt(int)` does and why do you think so? **Note the (int)!**

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? And add the full stacktrace please.

Comment: May have something to do with the fact that the method is taking in the wrong parameter type. I would suggest reading up on `indexOf()`

Comment: Read the Java documentation for `charAt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `t.indexOf(",")` instead of `t.charAt(',')` would work the way you want.

Comment: I misunderstoof the function thaought the input was a char to serach for not a index

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
p=t.charAt(',')
```

',' is equivalent to 44 according to the ASCII table.

Since your String has less than 44 characters you get the IndexOutOfBoundException.